# How to fix Integer Overflow warning in oyente?

Tags: solidity, remix, data-types

I was working with smart contracts and was testing my contracts using oyente. I am getting integer overflow warning in my contract and i dont know how to fix it. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance. Also i have a doubt, there are addresses mensioned in the smart contracts and the address of the accouns are to be taken from the metamask wallet connected to the remix account but while testing in oyente there wont be any value to the address mensioned in the program but why am i getting some random number in the integer overflow warning ??

[image]

Comment: They seems to be false positives. I won't blindly trust oyente.

Comment: Oh then okey, false positives cases may occur. @Ismael Thanks for your reply.